# ExtJS tpl renders twice

Tags: extjs4

ExtJS 4.2.2

The test code below is not rendering what I would expect
I would expect to see:

```
Hello Effy
```

instead I am seeing

```
Hello Effy

Hello
```

the HTML from FireFox is

```
<div id="test-1002" class="x-component x-fit-item" style="margin: 0px; width: 800px; height: 126px;">

    <p>
        Hello Effy
    </p>
    <p>
        Hello 
    </p>
</div>
```

with itemSelector commented out I get a blank screen

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

TIA

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.view.View',
    alias: 'widget.test',

    itemSelector: '',    
    data:{name:"Effy"},
    tpl: ["<p>Hello {name}</p>"],

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `tpl` config is the template for the whole view, which means you need to provide the iteration. It gives you the freedom to do stuff like:

```
Some heading
<tpl for=".">
    <div class="foo">{name}</div>
</tpl>
Some footer
```

Assuming you just want to set the template for each item, use the `itemTpl` config:

```
itemTpl: '<p>Hello {name}</p>'
```

Comment: Learning EXTJS 4 says one way to add HTML to a component is with the tpl/data configs. I was trying this out when this undesired behaivour occurred.

Comment: That's different. The tpl in a `Ext.view.View` has a special meaning, because it's store backed. If you're looking for simple data binding, try the same code as you have, but extend `Ext.Component`.